# Not visible content of WindowsFormsHost when added to WrapPanel in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

EDIT: To introduce quickly: `WindowsFormsHost` added by `xaml` has all contents. Added by `C#` has no contents---> pictures below.

When I insert a `WindowsFormsHost` in the `WrapPanel x:Name = "VideoPanel"` by the `XAML` and then add `VideoStream videoStream` in the **.cs** file, conents of VideoStream are visible in the that `WrapPanel`. Everything is OK contents are visible(screenshot below).

Adnotation: `VideoStream` extends `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`

**XAML:**

```
   <WrapPanel x:Name="VideoPanel" >
               <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2">
                        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Host" Width="400" Height="400"></WindowsFormsHost>
                    </Border>
   </WrapPanel>
```

**.cs File:**

```
VideoStream videoStream = new VideoStream();
Host.Child = VideoStream;
```

**Result**(correct result):

[image]

---

**But** when I want to create and insert `WindowsFormsHost` and the `VideoStream` in the `WrapPanel` by  C# code there is only border visible with no contents. **How to make contents of `VideoStream` visible?**

**Code with which I have problem:**

```
   WindowsFormsHost formsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
        VideoStream videoStream = new VideoStream();
        formsHost.Child = videoStream;
        Border lineBorder = new Border();
        lineBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
        lineBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
        lineBorder.Child = new WindowsFormsHost();
        VideoPanel.Children.Add(lineBorder);
        videoStream.Height = 400;
        videoStream.Width = 400;
        lineBorder.Width = 400;
        lineBorder.Height = 400;
        formsHost.Width = 400;
        formsHost.Height = 400;
```

**XAML:**

```
  <WrapPanel x:Name="VideoPanel" >
            </WrapPanel>
```

**Result**(incorrect):

[image]

**How to make contents of `VideoStream` visible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line :

```
lineBorder.Child = new WindowsFormsHost();
```

Should be :

```
lineBorder.Child = formsHost;
```

You're creating a new windowsformshost and not using the proper one.